# Passing global variables as method params in java

Tags: java, concurrency, global-variables

This might be a very dumb question, but I still wanted to get an opinion on whether the code I am writing is correct or not.

```
public class Test {
    Map<String, Queue<Object>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String Queue<Object>> myMap2 = new HashMap<>();

    Test() {
        Queue<Object> testQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        Queue<Object> testQueue2 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        for (int i=0; i< 10; i++) {
            String myString = "myhello" + i;
            String myString2 = "blahsd" + i;
            testQueue.add(myString);
            testQueue2.add(myString2);
        }

        myMap.put("map1", testQueue);
        myMap2.put("map2", testQueue2;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Object obj = myMap.get("map1").poll();
        //dO operation on obj
        ...
        ...
        ...
        addObjectToMap(obj, myMap);


        Object obj2 = myMap2.get("map2").poll();
        //dO operation on obj
        ...
        ...
        ...
        addObjectToMap(obj2, myMap2);
    }

    public void addObjectToMap(Object obj, Map<String, Queue<Object>> params) {
        //getMapForKey() will return the available keys in the Map passed as argument to this method
        params.get(getMapForKey()).add(obj);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to know if its okay to pass in the global variable as a param to a method and whether updating the value in the method will actually update the global variable.

Another question is that if I run this code multithreaded, will concurrency cause any race conditions, which will prevent the maps to be updated with their actual values?

Comment: Have you tried _compiling_ your code?  Static methods cannot access non static member variables.  As for the concurrency question, yes you can have problems with your collections, unless you wrap them as thread safe.

Comment: I feeling is that even if you **can** do something consider how it affects your (and other peoples) understanding of the code

Comment: For static access I agree. This code is not compilable. According to concurrency, I do not expect any problems with it, because you do not modify HashMap, only ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

Comment: My apologies. In the example where I'm using this, there's no main method. Its a pure class and methods. And yeah the above example wouldn't generally compile as @Tim suggested